# Simple way to reverse alphabetical sort order in C++ std::priority_queue?

Tags: c++, data-structures, priority-queue, alphabetical

Hi I'm solving some kind of sorting algorithm problems.

I'm using C++ STL priority_queue with STL queue header to sort string input with reverse-alphabetical order with some integer numbers.

I know there's a simple idea to implement incremental order of integer sorting with priority queue like this.

```
#include <queue>

priority_queue<int> pq;
int arr[5] = {4,3,2,1,5};

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
   pq.push(-arr[i]);
while(!pq.empty()) {
   cout << -pq.top() << endl;
   pq.pop();
}
//the result may be 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

or I can implement like this by using less operator

```
priority_queue<int, vector<int>, less<int>> pq;
int arr[5] = {4,3,2,1,5};

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
   pq.push(arr[i]);
while(!pq.empty()) {
   cout << pq.top() << endl;
   pq.pop();
}
//the result may be 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

the problem is i'm using complicated datastructure like this

```
priority_queue<pair<int, pair<int, pair<int, string>>>> pq;
```

I know I can solve this problem with priority_queue operator overloading.

But is there any **simple and decent way** to implement reverse-alphabetical order without implementing operator overloading like this?

Answer (score 2):

**You should never use such complex data structure using nested pairs in real code anyway.** It make the code hard to understand. What is `pq.top().second.second.first`?

If your structure is complex, then define a structure with desired members like this (but with meaningful members' names):

```
struct datastructure
{
    int member1;
    int member2;
    int member3;
    std::string member4;
};
```

Then you should define a comparison operator. It is really only a few lines of code and it make your code much more readable. It can be a nested `struct` if you prefer...

```
struct datastructure_comp
{
    bool operator()(const datastructure &lhs, const datastructure &rhs) const
    {
        return lhs.member1 < rhs.member2;
    }
};
```

As far as I know, if you simply want to reverse the order of your complex data structure, you could use `std::greater` instead of the default `std::less` (assuming that all fields are to be compared in reverse order and not only the first one).

Well, if you want to still use pairs for simplicity, then you could do something like that:

```
class datastructure 
{
    std::pair<int, std::pair<int, std::pair<int, string>>>> data;

public:
    int GetValue1() const { return data.first; }
    void SetValue1(int value) { data.first = value; }

    // other access function here...
};
```

And then defining the comparison would be trivial:

```
struct datastructure_comp
{
    bool operator()(const datastructure &lhs, const datastructure &rhs) const
    {
        return lhs.data > rhs.data; // reversed sort...
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you, but that answer was not I want. I didn't asked you to how to make custom datastructure and comparison operator. I am curious about how to make ""simple"" reverse alphabetical sort order using priority queue like  pq.push(-arr[i]); focus on the title please

Comment: @JunsungChoi then you can't do it simple way because your data structure is not simple.

Comment: @JunsungChoi The answer **you** want is to use `std::greater` as already mentioned in my answer. However **professional developers** won't use 3 levels deep `std::pair` as it make the code hard to understand.